# Get executing directory in C++

Tags: c++, directory, windows-ce

I have a .CAB file that runs as part of an installer process on a Windows CE box.  The CAB is written in C++.

The CAB file is ran twice as part of an upgrade process but in different locations at different times.  How can I find out what directory the .CAB file is being executed from (executing directory) using C++ only?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the scenario. The CAB has duplicate disk images? It is run twice from the same image with explicit (different) start folders?  In both cases, wouldn't ::GetCurrentDirectory() suffice?

Comment: Windows CE hasn't "current directory" concept...

Comment: Why do you keep insisting on using the `wince` tag. It's redundant when you use `windows-ce` and `windows-ce` is clearer.

Comment: I didn't realise it was redundant? Perhaps just a bad habit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "C++ only" you mean without using Windows API, I don't think the standard library has a function to do that.

If you can call a Win32 API, you just have to call `GetModuleFileName()` with NULL as the first parameter, and you will get the path of the current executable.

Now, the problem is: we you run the .CAB, what is the executable? The install DLL extracted from the .CAB, or the shell component that is running the .CAB?

You can also try `GetCommandLine()`, as the first entry should be the executable path/name (it is actually the string passed to `CreateProcess()`, so you can't be 100% sure about it).

Comment: I have access to winbase so this should work, I'll try it now

Comment: This unfortunately only shows the path to wceload.exe that loads executes the cabfile and not the cabfile location itself :(

Comment: OK, so try with GetCommandLine(), hopefully you will see the path of the CAB as the parameter of wceload...